# Colorbox overflow is STILL set to hidden? (Trying to append)

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

I'm trying to append a div to the colorbox modal, and what I did was that I set the css settings to 'overflow: visible", and I also set changed every string in jquery.colorbox.js from hidden to visible, however this is what I have in firebug:

```
<div id="colorbox" class="" style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px; display: block; position: absolute; width: 796px; height: 300px; top: 164px; left: 442px; overflow: hidden;">
```

This is the CSS file of colorbox:

```
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9997; overflow:visible; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000000;}
/*#cboxOverlay{position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%;}*/
#cboxMiddleLeft, #cboxBottomLeft{clear:left;}
#cboxContent{position:relative; overflow: visible;}
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow:auto;}
#cboxTitle{margin:0;}
#cboxLoadingOverlay, #cboxLoadingGraphic{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%;}
#cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose, #cboxSlideshow{cursor:pointer;}
.cboxPhoto{float:left; margin:auto; border:0; display:block;}
.cboxIframe{width:100%; height:100%; display:block; border:0;}

/* 
    User Style:
    Change the following styles to modify the appearance of ColorBox.  They are
    ordered & tabbed in a way that represents the nesting of the generated HTML.
*/
#cboxOverlay{background:#212121;}
#colorbox{}
    #cboxContent{margin-top:0px; overflow:visible;}
        #cboxError{padding:50px; border:1px solid #fff;}
        #cboxLoadedContent{background:#000; padding:0px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;}
        #cboxLoadingGraphic{background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;}
        #cboxLoadingOverlay{background:#000;}
        #cboxTitle{position:absolute; top:-22px; left:0; color:#000;}
        #cboxCurrent{position:absolute; top:-22px; right:205px; text-indent:-9999px;}
        #cboxSlideshow, #cboxPrevious, #cboxNext, #cboxClose{text-indent:-9999px; width:20px; height:20px; position:absolute; top:-20px; background:url(images/controls.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
        #cboxPrevious{background-position:0px 0px; right:44px;}
        #cboxPrevious.hover{background-position:0px -25px;}
        #cboxNext{background-position:-25px 0px; right:22px;}
        #cboxNext.hover{background-position:-25px -25px;}
        #cboxClose{background-position:-50px 0px; right:0;}
        #cboxClose.hover{background-position:-50px -25px;}
        .cboxSlideshow_on #cboxPrevious, .cboxSlideshow_off #cboxPrevious{right:66px;}
        .cboxSlideshow_on #cboxSlideshow{background-position:-75px -25px; right:44px;}
        .cboxSlideshow_on #cboxSlideshow.hover{background-position:-100px -25px;}
        .cboxSlideshow_off #cboxSlideshow{background-position:-100px 0px; right:44px;}
        .cboxSlideshow_off #cboxSlideshow.hover{background-position:-75px -25px;}
```

Thank you :))))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `overflow:visible !important;` in your stylesheet, this isn't a very neat solution however if you can't find the original place where it is being set this could be a useful fix

Comment: Hmm, no luck. I changed the overflow to visible in firebug and that div is still not being shown. My code could be wrong as well.

Comment: Now it works! For everyone that's wondering: IN jquery.colorbox.js I did: $content = $div("Content").append(
   $loaded = $div("LoadedContent", 'width:0; height:0; overflow:visible'),

And appended the div to one of the divs INSIDE the colorbox. :)))

Comment: Actually, the reason why it worked was because of the visible !important line :))

Answer (score 0):

In colorbox.css on line #30 - remove #cboxClose, after line 30 insert new line and past this

```
#cboxClose{position:absolute; top:-29px; right:0; background:url(../i/controls.png) no-repeat -25px 0; width:25px; height:25px; text-indent:-9999px;}
```

That fix my problem with bad position of closing (x) button.